# Navigation disappears on Mobile site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I am having a small issue with my website.

When I open the site on my PC it works great with my navigation bar always on the top right of the website. But when I go on my phone, the bar is there but the navigation is gone (all the words can't fit).

How can I get it to turn into a drop down menu or something only on the mobile website.

Look at this website:  http://thebestgui.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my friend 
your website is bootstrap ...
and the btn is over there

just add this code to your CSS and it will work .

```
.res-nav_click {color: #fff;}
```

Comment: your web site is HTML from first look your CSS file on this path
http://thebestgui.com/css/style.css
add the code I gave you at the end of the file

Comment: if it work for you please dont forget to mark my answer so the issue will be resolved .

Comment: Thank you. It was is that easy lol

Comment: you just need to know how to look at the problem to fix the source :)